# Flask SQLAlchemy customer orm?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

My model is like this:

```
class A(db.Model):
   __tablename__ = 'tablename'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   users = Column(String(128))
```

But most of time, I use the users field as list.

In java ORM I can declared this field as list just by tell the framework how to map string to list and list to string.

So I wonder there is any way to do this in Flask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom type with [TypeDecorator](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html#sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator)

```
import sqlalchemy.types as types


class MyList(types.TypeDecorator):
    impl = types.String

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        return ','.join(value)

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        return value.split(',')


class A(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tablename'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    users = Column(MyList)


a = A(users=['user1', 'user2'])
db.session.add(a)
db.session.commit()
A.query.first().users
>> [u'user1', u'user2']
```